# Discord JS user botting

Tags: discord, discord.js

#### Logging in with a user account.

Ok so, I noticed that it's extremely easy to use a bot with Python on Discord, but it's not possible on Node JS? I mean, there must be a way to log in to a user account with Node JS, anybody know?

### Error

Whenever trying to log in to a user account with discord.js, it replies with this:

```sh
Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
```

I'm pretty curious; I'd like to make something that would react with "uwu" every time someone says "uwu".

Comment: First of all, self botting is strictly against Discord TOS. Second of all are you using the correct token?

Comment: Rules are meant to be followed :/

Comment: Some rules are meant to be broken -Zombieland 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/botkalista/discord.js.userbot

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const allowUserBotting = require('discord.js.userbot');
const client = new Discord.Client();
allowUserBotting(client);
client.login('YOUR USER TOKEN HERE');
```

Answer (score 3):

Different libraries, different degrees of freedom. You observed it is not possible with discord.js but it is possible with discord.py.
Either use the Python library or you edit the JavaScript library.

[From discord.js:](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/77b6a7d5bd7463f9f397179f5897ec0d00706749/src/util/Util.js#L243)

```
headers: { Authorization: `Bot ${token.replace(/^Bot\s*/i, '')}` },
```

[From discord.py:](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/7126f5a78c4d08833ee42e3ba75cc5b8b5ac84c4/discord/http.py#L152)

```
headers['Authorization'] = 'Bot ' + self.token if self.bot_token else self.token
```

The only difference between the two of them is the Authorization header. In discord.py when a Bot token is supplied the token is prefixed with `Bot` . When a User token is supplied there is no `Bot`  prefix.
In discord.js the `Bot`  prefix is always supplied leading it to only work with bot tokens.

This is the most help I'll offer. If you can't do anything with this information then you are on your own.

Comment: This is only for Sharding, and this does not work for logging in.

Comment: ```const client = new Discord.Client({ _tokenType: '' });```
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/client/Client.js#L35
Have fun :)

Comment: If you login with a self bot but don't send any messages to channels and only listen, will you get banned?

Comment: @Sendai maybe. Discord hasn't exampled any scenario where it would be allowed. They have however said that it may get you banned.  
It will be obvious to Discord that you are self botting. The discord libraries behave different than the official discord client and discord web client. With a self bot you are receiving all message events from all guilds. With the official client you are only receiving message events from the current actively selected guild. You can inspect the websocket traffic of your discord web client and you'll see you don't receive all messages.

Answer (score 0):

I guess they must have patched user botting on discord.js. I switched from `13.5.0` to an older version where it worked: `11.3.2`.

package.json

```
...
    "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^11.3.2",
...
```

Of course, if you need some feature introduced in a newer version, this solution may not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**User token support was removed after `v11.6.4`.**
It's the latest usable/semi-stable version that provides user token support...

So add `"discord.js": "11.6.4",` to your package.json dependencies and have fun!

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "11.6.4"
    }
}
```

OR
Just use one of the answers that these fine people provided (This is what I'm going to do)

Answer (score -3):

yesterday discord passing user's token for selfbots

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all(), command_prefix='>', self_bot=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('#######################################')
    print('Logged in as')
    print(f"User : {bot.user.name}")
    print(f"ID : {bot.user.id}")
    print('########################################')

TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

**  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 805, in static_login
raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.**