# Is there a way to login to a discord client as a user rather than a bot from a js file?

Tags: discord.js

Basically I want to see if I can get a bot to run commands on a different bot. But because of that limitation, I am now trying to login to my discord from the js file so that I can control my account autonomously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JS user botting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673014/discord-js-user-botting)

Comment: it does, dang I didnt know it was against TOS, I just wanted to take over the Karrot economy