# selfbot.py +> from exc discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have a answering machin with selfbot in python and is was healthy
im wondering when i slept and wakedup (my windows got crashed and couldnt repair it)
after i install new windows/python and run my selfbot i got this error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'`

I installed discord then i see this

```
client = discord.Client() # represents a client object
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

After i put code like this

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

```
[2022-12-18 00:10:13] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RaDaN\Desktop\Python\3.py", line 58, in <module>
    client.run(token) # starting the bot
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 805, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

**selfbot code is here**

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents) # represents a client object
token = ""
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Online !!!!")

async def on_message(message):

    if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return
    if "<@808641904220700724>" in message.content:
        print("Find Mention")
        print(f"Server : {message.guild}  Channel : {message.channel} Author {message.author}: {message.content}")
        await message.channel.send(f"Report Sent i'll Contact You ASAP :heart: Content : :pushpin:Server : {message.guild} :pushpin:Channel : {message.channel.id} :pushpin:Author : {message.author.mention} :pushpin:ID : {message.author.id}")

    if "رادان" in message.content:
        print("Find نادار")
        print(f"Server : {message.guild}  Channel : {message.channel} Author {message.author}: {message.content}")
        await message.channel.send(f"Report Sent i'll Contact You ASAP :heart: Content : :pushpin:Server : {message.guild} :pushpin:Channel : {message.channel.id} :pushpin:Author : {message.author.mention} :pushpin:ID : {message.author.id}")
        
    if "radan" in message.content:
        print("Find radan")
        print(f"Server : {message.guild}  Channel : {message.channel} Author {message.author}: {message.content}")
        await message.channel.send(f"Report Sent i'll Contact You ASAP :heart: Content : :pushpin:Server : {message.guild} :pushpin:Channel : {message.channel.id} :pushpin:Author : {message.author.mention} :pushpin:ID : {message.author.id}")


    if "Radan" in message.content:
        print("Find Radan")
        print(f"Server : {message.guild}  Channel : {message.channel} Author {message.author}: {message.content}")
        await message.channel.send(f"Report Sent i'll Contact You ASAP :heart: Content : :pushpin:Server : {message.guild} :pushpin:Channel : {message.channel.id} :pushpin:Author : {message.author.mention} :pushpin:ID : {message.author.id}")        

client.run(token)
```

I wondering is that error coming from discord or something wrong in my work?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a valid token and everything is set up properly in Discord?

Comment: yeah i used it befor in right way (at authorization in header
also i use token graber for geting token

Answer (score 0):

I can assume (and hope) that your token is not "". Anyways, your receiving two errors (mainly relating to one) in the third error you posted (by the way, I think the intents thing is fine, I think you can also put None but just to be safe keep your current).

**You are getting a 401 unauthorized error and an improper token passed error.**
Both of these show your token is bad.

Try these steps and tell me if they don't work:

- Head to the [Discord Applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) page and open your application.
- Make sure your token that you are putting in your code **is from the "bot" menu of your application** (you may need to click "Reset Token" to get the token).
- An example token looks like this: `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`. If your token looks different (in length), then you may have copied the wrong value.

This should work, but on the small chance it doesn't, reply in the comments and I will gladly help you troubleshoot.

Hope this helps!

Comment: sure i hidden it for reason u know . , as i know it was working as well 12 hours ago
and i didnt put bot token , its my account's token

Comment: @Radan That's not how Discord.JS works at all - it needs to be a bot token.

Comment: Also, @Radan, that's against the discord TOS (self-botting).
Good job on hiding your token, though! Some new users do expose their tokens.

I'd suggest you get a bot token. If you want more information, check [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673014/discord-js-user-botting).

Hope this helps!